# Root privileges in OpenShift Online gears

Tags: linux, openshift, redhat

I created a java application on Openshift. I am able to login to my linux instance using my username and my private key. Now i need to install a third party software on my linux instance but when i try to do that it say Permission Denied.

> /usr/bin/install: cannot create regular file
>   `/usr/local/lib/libogg.so.0.8.2': Permission denied

The reason for this is that i am not logged in as root.

I have scoured through net for like 6 hrs now and didn't find any solution how to login as root in my redhat linux server to install the software. I don't want to change the default install scripts. I am using a free version of Redhat.

Help Required!

Comment: What command do you use to install the software? Try to use ´sudo` maybe? Would be like so `sudo <command>`.

Comment: There is ./configure command. This script does the install and at one of the steps it creates a folder in lib directory and it say permission denied because i am not logged in as root. I tried sudo command as well and it says permission denied.

Comment: Maybe you missed something in the readme or instructions? If the script needs privileges I imagine the setuid flag should be set then? Try to set the flag `setuid`?

Comment: No I mean when the script run at one of the steps it creates a folder and because i am logged in as a normal user in my linux instance the folder creation fails due to permission. If i login as root it will run successfully. I am trying to understand how to login to my linux instance (RHEL) as a root or how to create a root user.

Comment: I see. Did you try `su`?

Comment: have you tried setting up sudeors?

Comment: @unixmiah after your comment i googled it and found this link [Create Sudeors](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux_OpenStack_Platform/2/html/Getting_Started_Guide/ch02s03.html). The very first step in this it says is login as root and thats what i am trying to figure out how to do it? :)

Comment: depending on the distribution a simple sudo su will switch you to the root user.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you refer to [OpenShift Online](https://developers.openshift.com/) (cloud PaaS) gear that you are sshing into as to:

> my redhat linux server

If that is the case, please note that users do not have root privileges on their OpenShift Online gears.

---

If you have your own RHEL server, you should know your root credentials. If it's a different server/not installed by you, you would need to ask its admin to add you to sudoers.

Comment: You are correct. I am referring to OpenShift Online(Cloud PaaS) gear. I need to install a streaming server on the OpenShift Online linux server and while running the ./configure script, the script tries to create a directory in /usr/local/lib/ where my logged in user don't have access. How can i install the software on OpenShift Online gear?

Comment: As answered you can't, you don't have the permission to install your software on the OpenShift platform.

Answer (score 0):

i think use two command for software installation like as

1. **#yum install software package**
2. **#rpm  -ivh  software package**

   we use **redhat** linux

Comment: do you use redhat linux server or Openshift Cloud Online PaaS?